# Place list of items in div box

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML and CSS. I am currently trying to make the list of items (Edit|Delete|Review|Take Test) into my div box but I couldn't figure out why it is always outside of the box.

[image]

```css
.action-container {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid rgba(74, 74, 74, 0.075);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #204056;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Roboto", "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#menu>li.sub ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  float: right;
}

#menu li.sub ul li a {
  display: inline;
}

#menu {
  text-align: right;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="action-container">
  <p>Test 1</p>
  <ul id="menu">
    <li class="sub"><a href="#">Edit</a> | </li>
    <li class="sub"><a href="#">Delete</a> | </li>
    <li class="sub"><a href="#">Review</a> | </li>
    <li class="sub"><a href="#">Take Test</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Edit: I want Test1 and (Edit|Delete|Review|Take Test) to be on the same line

Comment: Please remove height: 70px;

Comment: Thank you. How to make them on the same line? After removing the height, the list are below the "Test 1"

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `display: flex;` with `justify-content: space-between;`

```css
.action-container {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid rgba(74, 74, 74, 0.075);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #204056;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Roboto", "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1em;
}

#menu, .action-container p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="action-container">
  <p>Test 1</p>
  <ul id="menu">
    <li class="sub"><a href="#">Edit</a> | </li>
    <li class="sub"><a href="#">Delete</a> | </li>
    <li class="sub"><a href="#">Review</a> | </li>
    <li class="sub"><a href="#">Take Test</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Super Sir I like Your Answer @Michael Coker

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `height:auto` and change the style for `p` to `float:Left`.

```css
.action-container {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid rgba(74, 74, 74, 0.075);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #204056;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Roboto", "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.action-container p {
  float: left;
  max-width: 70%;
}

#menu>li.sub ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  float: right;
}

#menu li.sub ul li a {
  display: inline;
}

#menu {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="action-container">
  <p>Test 1</p>
  <ul id="menu">
    <li class="sub"><a href="#">Edit</a> | </li>
    <li class="sub"><a href="#">Delete</a> | </li>
    <li class="sub"><a href="#">Review</a> | </li>
    <li class="sub"><a href="#">Take Test</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change display inline-block to table. It will work. I don't know why but I use it quite a lot in my projects.

```css
.action-container {
    display:table;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid rgba(74,74,74,0.075);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #204056;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: "Roboto", "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#menu > li.sub ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    float: right;
}

#menu li.sub ul li a {
    display: inline;
}

#menu{
    text-align:right;
}

li{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="action-container">
  <p>Test 1</p>
  <ul id="menu">
    <li class="sub"><a href="#">Edit</a> | </li>
    <li class="sub"><a href="#">Delete</a> | </li>
    <li class="sub"><a href="#">Review</a> | </li>
    <li class="sub"><a href="#">Take Test</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to float left on your branding text like so

```
<p style="float:left">Test 1</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Please Try This

**HTML**

```
<div class="action-container">
       <p>Test 1</p>
           <ul id="menu">
               <li class="sub"><a href="#">Edit</a> | </li>
               <li class="sub"><a href="#">Delete</a> | </li>
               <li class="sub"><a href="#">Review</a> | </li>
               <li class="sub"><a href="#">Take Test</a></li>
            </ul>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.action-container {
    display:inline-block;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 70px;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid rgba(74,74,74,0.075);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #204056;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: "Roboto", "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.action-container p { float: left;width: 70%; }
#menu > li.sub ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    float: right;
}

#menu li.sub ul li a {
    display: inline;
}

#menu{
   float: right;
margin-right: 10px;
}

li{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well that's because of `p tag` see below example,

**Example - 1**

I have assigned `background color` to `p tag` and you can see that it takes `full width`, because you have assigned `text-align left` in `parent div` and float to `ul tag` and it `float to right`, but to make that align inside box you have to assign `float` to `p tag` too.

```css
.action-container {
    display:inline-block;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid rgba(74,74,74,0.075);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #204056;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: "Roboto", "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.action-container  > p{
  background:#ccc;
}
#menu > li.sub ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    float: right;
}

#menu li.sub ul li a {
    display: inline;
}

#menu{
    text-align:right;
}

li{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="action-container">
       <p>Test 1</p>
           <ul id="menu">
               <li class="sub"><a href="#">Edit</a> | </li>
               <li class="sub"><a href="#">Delete</a> | </li>
               <li class="sub"><a href="#">Review</a> | </li>
               <li class="sub"><a href="#">Take Test</a></li>
            </ul>
  </div>
```

**Example - 2**
Output after adding float to `p tag`,

```css
.action-container {
    display:inline-block;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid rgba(74,74,74,0.075);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #204056;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: "Roboto", "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.action-container  > p{
  float:left;
}
#menu > li.sub ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    float: right;
}

#menu li.sub ul li a {
    display: inline;
}

#menu{
    text-align:right;
}

li{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="action-container">
       <p>Test 1</p>
           <ul id="menu">
               <li class="sub"><a href="#">Edit</a> | </li>
               <li class="sub"><a href="#">Delete</a> | </li>
               <li class="sub"><a href="#">Review</a> | </li>
               <li class="sub"><a href="#">Take Test</a></li>
            </ul>
  </div>
```